# RunTime errors and Cells() property fails inside Workbook_SheetChange

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a simple tracking procedure, but can't teach it properly fill the report line by line.

The idea is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'define last row in report
    <proper code for it>

    'fill in "last row +1" with tracking info
     <proper code for it as well>

End Sub
```

So i've tried two options:

1) With Cells() property (instead of `Offset` there might be just `LastRow + 1` for row index)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = 1

End Sub
```

And it results in multiple rows filling with desired values. Strangely it always took 93 rows down of the chosen cell after each change in the worksheet (so 93 186 279 372 465 558).

2) With Range() property:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 1).Value = 1

End Sub
```

Then it properly fill required cell, but then constantly results in

> run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108): method range of object
>   _worksheet failed

And in one of three times it also make Excel crash.

Comment: Is that *Workbook_SheetChange* on the **Sheets(1)** code sheet or are you trying to put a *1* into a different worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code triggers the SheetChange event because the code writes to the sheet so the code creates a recurring loop. Try turning events off and then back on again.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = 1
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, man, this is brilliant. It was the first time, when I failed to find an answer myself in this site and in google, so I was even forced to sing here up :)
And it was worth that )

Comment: If the OP is trying to write to the same worksheet that triggered the event, the *ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)* can be eliminated. It only causes confusion and could result in a different worksheet receiving the *1* if the worksheets were reordered.

Comment: to:Jeeped
Well, surely, there is meaningfull name of the sheet, I've just simplified the code for my example here.
BTW, how to reference particular user in my answer? )

Comment: Simply prefix the user's name with the @ character (e.g. @Gurov Stepan) to show that you are replying to their comment

Comment: @ChipsLetten Thanks. Quite obvious actually. Should have guessed myself.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably re-triggering *Events.*  Disable events before:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = 1
```

and re-enable them afterwards.